# How can I find what click events are linked to a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, console, click, jquery-events

If I have the following HTML markup:

```
<div class="foo">bar</div>
```

How can I find which click events are linked to this element / jQuery selector?

Is there a way I can get a list of file locations or something using Google Chrome Console?

---

Say I have the following jQuery:

```
$(".foo").click(function(){
  //do something
});

$("div").click(function(){
  //do something else
});

$("table").click(function(){
  //do something else
});
```

I would want something like:

> foobar.js (line 1)
>
> foobar.js (line 4)

Comment: Read through this tutorial http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/things-you-may-not-know-about-jquery/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should help. It is based on this [link](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/things-you-may-not-know-about-jquery/). **Is this what you want?**

```
// List bound events:
console.dir( jQuery('#elem').data('events') );

// Log ALL handlers for ALL events:
jQuery.each($('#elem').data('events'), function(i, event){
    jQuery.each(event, function(i, handler){
        console.log( handler.toString() );
    });
});
```

Comment: I've tried running that in console, but I don't understand the response, and that blog post doesn't really give any explanation

Comment: You have to modify that code according to your need. Show me what have you done.

Comment: I've modified it to the correct selectors, but the response was a bit confusing. I think I've almost worked it out though, will report back

Comment: Thanks this has helped. It doesn't display what line number, but it displays the entire function, so I was able to do a "Find in files" to find the functions

Answer (score 0):

There is something called [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event). You can know all event handlers attached to DOM elements.